# Convergence speed for iterative methods

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I am a bit confused about convergence rates of iterative methods. Why do we say that a method converges linearly, if the error decreases exponentially with each step, i.e.

$$d(x^{i}, x^*) \leq \lambda^i d(x^1, x^*), \quad \lambda \in (0,1)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also call that geometric convergence. The "linear" refers to the fact that the reference error on the right side only appears in the first power. With quadratic convergence you would get
$$
d(x^{i+1},x^∗)≤λd(x^i,x^∗)^2\implies d(x^i,x^∗)\leλ^{2^i-1}d(x^0,x^∗)^{2^i}
$$
which converges to zero if $λd(x^0,x^∗)<1$. This extends to similar formulas for  higher order convergence.

---

Be careful of where you start your sequence, the linear convergence formula should be
$$
d(x^i,x^∗)\leλ^{i-1}d(x^1,x^∗)
$$
as you can check when comparing the initial condition at $i=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The error between *consecutive iterations* behaves linearly. That is to say, if $\epsilon_n$ is the error of the $n$th iteration, then the convergence is linear iff

$$\epsilon_{n+1}\le \lambda\epsilon_n$$

for some $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and all sufficiently large $n$. Similarly, one says that the convergence is quadratic iff

$$\epsilon_{n+1}\le\lambda\epsilon_n^2$$

(not necessarily with $\lambda\in(0,1)$, but any $\lambda>0$) and likewise for cubic, quartic, etc. In general, the convergence is said to be polynomial when of this form.